# Issue with hover effect on image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hello i am trying to create hover effect on img.

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    <div class="link-cont"><a href="#">click here to see more info</a></div>

</div>
```

css

```
div {
    width: 350px;
position: relative;    
}
.link-cont {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:hover  .link-cont {
    opacity: 1; 
    bottom:-100px;
}
```

i need a something like this , when the user hover on it
[image]

but i am getting something like this

[image: current]

can someone help me to achieve what i am trying to do..

jsFid--> http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/

Comment: what should happen on hover? the `div` should under the image?

Comment: yes.. div should under the image..

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/3/

Comment: no... like the first image that i have posted here in my question..

Comment: ok, and starting point is just image?

Comment: I am really sorry about my bad English

Comment: when i hover on the image the red div should appears underneath the image and the "click here.." link should be under the image and the image need to be centered..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want like this, check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Nnd7w/17/

```
div {
    width: 350px;
    font-size:12px;
    position: relative;    
}
div img{
    padding:0 10px;    
}
.link-cont {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 370px;
    height: 210px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    z-index: -1
}
div:hover  .link-cont {
    opacity: 1; 
    bottom:-40px;
}
.link-cont a{    
    opacity: 0;  
}
div:hover  .link-cont a{
    position: relative; 
    opacity: 1; 
    bottom:-175px;
    left:10px;
    background:#fff;
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: The only problem I find with this is that when I hover over the image - You can see the link at the top of the red box in blue and underlined and watch it go down and turn to a white background. Kinda funky - sat there for a few seconds just staring at it >< lol.

Comment: Please add this new css to hide this link, .link-cont a{ 
    opacity: 0;  
}

Answer (score 3):

Try this - and let me know if it works for you..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/10/)

Just a few changes - Could use some cleaning up.

```
     div {
     position: relative;
     top: 50px;
     background-color: blue;
     width: 350px;
     height: 150px;
     margin: auto;
 }
 .link-cont {
     background: red;
     position: relative;
     left: -50px;
     top: -200px;
     width: 450px;
     height: 250px;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.4s;
     z-index: -1
 }
 div a {
     position: relative;
     top: 210px;
     left: 50px;
     opacity: 0;
 }
 div:hover .link-cont {
     opacity: 1;
 }
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
 div:hover a {
     opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: YES THIS IS WHAT I NEDED. and i change few properties.. http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/14/

Comment: I guess someone beat me to the answer ^-^

Comment: Haha me too.  However, mine only activates when you hover over the image itself.  He might not need that, though.

Comment: @nondefault , Lloan Alas , UmairP  He gave 100% suitable answer to my question :). But Thank you guy.. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Made a few modifications to you CSS

```
div {
    width: 370px;
    position: relative;
}
.link-cont {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 370px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    z-index: -1
}
div:hover .link-cont {
    opacity: 1;
}
div:hover img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.link {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 170px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Instead of playing with bottom property, I just changed opacity. I also assigned a class to anchor tag to make it display under the image. Also, you can see I have given some margin to the image to make it center and changed the width and height of your link-count div.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pNuc/)

Answer (score 1):

I just changed `bottom:-100px;` to `top: 160px;` and it works fine!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/4/)

Edit: Some more options because I don't understand:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/6/), and the one I think you want: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nnd7w/13/) (that one's messy, but the hover only activates if you actually hover on the image.)

Comment: Thanks but i need something like the first image that i have posted here.